# Setear token en consulta a API net core 5 desde mvc net core

Tags: .net, .net-core

> La situación me resulta un poco complicada de explicar pero voy a tratar de hacerlo lo mejor posible.

Tengo una web cliente hecha en net core 5 y una API REST también hecha en net core 5; la api usa autenticación por medio de jwt. Desde el cliente manejo la comunicación con la api a través de una capa de servicios, en la cual se implementa servicios proxy que contiene el httpcliente para realizar las peticiones a las api. Los métodos de estos servicios proxy son llamados por otros servicios principales: hay un servicio en particular llamado *UsuarioServices* que maneja todo lo relacionado con los datos de usuarios; dentro de este servicio se encuentra un método de login que llama a varios métodos del servicio proxy llamado *UsuarioServiceProxy*, más específicamente a 2, uno para buscar el usuario por mail y otro para buscar a un usuario por username.

Bien, desde cliente trabajo con MVC y desde el controller de login inyecto el servicio UsuarioService, genero el token y lo seteo por medio de un método sincrónico que contiene el servicio de usuarios que lo que hace es llamar a un método del servicio proxy de usuario, también sincrónico que setea el token.

```
    public void SetToken(string token)
    {
        _HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
    }
```

el token lo genero de la siguiente manera desde el controlador por medio de un método privado:

```
    private string JwtGenerate(UserData userData)
    {
        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var tokenKey = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_tokenConfiguration.SigningKey);
        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
            {
                new Claim("username", userData.Username),
                new Claim("origen", "OPC")
            }),
            Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(10),
            SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(tokenKey), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
        };
        var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
        return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
    }
```

Luego en el método de login hago lo siguiente:

```
     public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginVM login)
    {
        
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) {

            Msg.Error("Ingrese todos los datos");
            return View("Index");
        }

        login.UsernameEmail = login.UsernameEmail.Trim().ToLower();
        UserData userData = new UserData()
        {
            Username = login.UsernameEmail,
            Contraseña = login.Password
        };
        string jwtToken = JwtGenerate(userData);

        _usuariosService.SetToken(jwtToken);


     
        LoginData loginData = new LoginData();
        loginData.UsernameEmail = login.UsernameEmail.ToLower();
        loginData.Password = login.Password;

        //ACA ESTA EL PROBLEMA
        ServicesResponse<UserData> sr = await _usuariosService.Login(loginData);


        if (sr.Code > 300 || sr.Data == null)
        {

            Msg.Error(sr.Message);
            return RedirectToAction("index");
        }

      //MAS CODIGO IRRELEVANTE...
        return RedirectToAction ("Index","Home");
    }
```

El método de login data que es donde tengo problema es el siguiente:

```
public async Task<ServicesResponse<UserData>> Login(LoginData loginData) 
    {
        ServicesResponse<UserData> result = null;

        if (loginData.UsernameEmail.Contains('@'))
        {
            result = await _comerciosProxy.GetUserByEmail(loginData.UsernameEmail);
        }
        else
        {
            result = await _comerciosProxy.GetUserByUsername(loginData.UsernameEmail);
        }

        if (result.Code >= 500)
        {
            return new ServicesResponse<UserData>()
            {
                Code = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
                Message = "Ocurrio un error inesperado"
            };
        }

        if (result.Code > 400)
        {
            return new ServicesResponse<UserData>()
            {
                Code = (int)HttpStatusCode.NoContent,
                Message = result.Message

            };
        }

        //string encryptPass = _encryptService.MD5Hash(loginData.Password);
        if (result.Data.Contraseña != loginData.Password)
        {
            result.Message = "Contraseña incorrecta";
            result.Code = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        }

        if (!result.Data.Habilitado)
        {
            result.Message = "El usuario no esta habilitado";
            result.Code = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

métodos *GetUserByEmail* y *GetUserByUsername*:

```
public async Task<ServicesResponse<UserData>> GetUserByEmail(string email)
    {
        try
        {
            string Url = $"{_Url}/Usuarios/email/{email}";
            HttpResponseMessage result = await _HttpClient.GetAsync(Url);

            return await result.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<ServicesResponse<UserData>>();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log(ex);
            return new ServicesResponse<UserData>()
            {
                Code = _CodeError,
                Message = _ErrorMsg,
                Data = null
            };
        }
    }

    public async Task<ServicesResponse<UserData>> GetUserByUsername(string username)
    {
        try
        {

            string Url = $"{_Url}/Usuarios/username/{username}";
            HttpResponseMessage result = await _HttpClient.GetAsync(Url);
            return await result.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<ServicesResponse<UserData>>();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log(ex);
            return new ServicesResponse<UserData>()
            {
                Code = _CodeError,
                Message = _ErrorMsg,
                Data = null
            };
        }
    }
```

Resulta que en la llamada al método login a veces responde con un 200 o con un 401 (en mi caso representa usuario no autorizado o sea como que no asignó el token correctamente). No sé qué puede ser porque es algo aleatorio, lo único que encontré como solución temporal fue agregar un `threath.sleep(2000)` entre la generación del token y la función login, esto funciona la mayoría de las veces (aunque no en todas). Intenté agregando un delay de 2 segundos a la tarea y no funciona, ocurre lo mismo, con la misma frecuencia. Probé apuntado localmente al proyecto de la api y no hubo problema. El problema surge cuando se publica, en un principio pensé que podía ser un tema de velocidad de procesador ya que en el servidor ocurría con poca o nula frecuencia esto, y en el equipo de desarrollo era más frecuente que pasara, sin embargo últimamente esta empezando a suceder lo mismo en el servidor de producción.

Comment: Nada más por preguntar: ¿ _threath_ o _thread_?

Comment: La pregunta esta bien.. pero no me queda claro tu problema.. alguien te devuelve un 200 o 400, y vos pensas que el problema lo tenes vos??? o nos falta esa parte???

Comment: @gbianchi exacto me devuelve 200 o 401, yo pensé que podría estar asignándose incorrectamente el token al ser tareas asincrónicas quizás hace la request antes de que se asigne el token, pero eso lo descarte porque cuando hice el debug el token estaba el header del request,  pero lo probe desde el swagger de la api y funcionaba pero la app con ese mismo token me tiraba un 400, por eso tambien descarte que sea la api.